# Can I use `base/pgsql_tmp` directory for non-admin applications?

Tags: postgresql, file-system

((
  edit after answer: this is a typical 
  [XY question/problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/205446), 
  there are **no restriction on use absolute path**, 
  on PostgreSQL's FileSystem functions. As @LaurenzAlbe comment, "just try".
))

---

I need to export/import JSON files, CSV files, XML, GeoJSON, etc. Example:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
SELECT pg_catalog.pg_file_write(
  'base/pgsql_tmp/test1_hello.txt',
  E'Hello\n\n\tWorld!',
  false
);
```

All are temporary (exists in a BEGIN/COMMIT), but no problem?

1. no risk on filename conflict? (e.g. my filename and a pgsql's managed temporary table filename)
2. no risk of directory (`base`) volume overflow? (e.g. when I save a big file there)
3. no risk on read-and-write sequences over same filename? They will be synchronous on BEGIN/COMMIT  sections?

---

### NOTES AND CONTEXT

Sometimes we can say that "database servers aren't designed for general file I/O" ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48456116/287948)), but sometimes we need it (!),  to simplify and automatize [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) or [interface](http://postgrest.org/) procedures.

About item 1 and the practical use, to simplify export/import procedures (and not need to remember where is `data_directory`), is perhaps better to create a `${data_directory}/base/pgsql_tmp/MyArea` as symbolic link to other area  (e. eg. `/tmp/MyRealArea`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1:

It is a bad idea to create these files in the PostgreSQL data directory.  That is for database files only.  In addition, you cannot be certain that `pgsql_tmp` is there at all (it is only created when the first temporary file is written).

Use an absolute path and write the file somewhere else, ideally in `/var`.

### Question 2

Of course there is a risk to fill up the file system - either through the files that you write, or through temporary files that the database writes.

### Question 3

That is up to your code; the database does not guarantee that you don't write over the same file in two concurrent transactions.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thanks!  About your *"use an absolute ... `/var` ..."* suggestion, seems impossible, [`pg_catalog.pg_file_write()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/adminpack.html)  only writes  at `$data_directory`.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine. Of course the PostgreSQL operating system user (typically `postgres`) must have write permissions on the directory.